# Think im being hacked

Tags: google-play-store, settings, data-transfer, active-sync, system-info

Firstly I'm a technophobe,totally useless and accept that hence why I need advice and answers before I lose my mind...

I believe my old friend and of recent girlfriend could be hacking me. I dont check often but happen to browse my activity abd noticed sight or applications I've never heard of let alone used further more they were all similar and close together so I'm sure I would know if searched. So in looking up some of these sites / apps they are legitimate but also could all be used to munipilate me.  The sites were....
..Com.android systemui
..com.samsung accessibility
..com.android settings
..google play store device connected,...I read your article and can confirm I don't or have ever connected or used another device, this activity was at the very same time that I was on my phone looking at a site about claiming company petrol spend,so naturally worries me
..com.samsung.android.messenging
..Com.OSP app sing in
Com.samsung.android.vision intelligence
..com.sec.android app camera
..com.samsung.android dialer
..com.android server telecom
Com.samsung.android incallui

These were in order of searches which started a 13:42 and ended at 17:39 there was a few searches repeated a couple of times like settings and accessibility.

Like I said I don't ir gave I ever used another device, no tablet, second phone nothing, all I gave done in the past is used smartphone on th TV but nit for some time.  Please please help me and help turn thus language into a course of intended actions I can understand...thank u

FOZ

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! First, you mostly can calm down: none of those indicate "hacking". You'd wonder what apps come pre-installed you never heard of – especially on a Samsung device (see an [example listing here](https://izzy.codeberg.page/adebar/110s20fe.html#System_Apps)). All the ones you've mentioned belong into that category, and many of them you even actively use without maybe noticing (SystemUI for example). So just because you see those names in a listing of recent activities doesn't mean you're hacked – it simply means your phone works as expected ;)

Comment: Thank you izzy very kind and I do understand my concern is that I don't think she's hacking in a keyboard wizard way she has all my personal details and I know she knows main passwords so I think it's more using an alternative device and signing in as me and looking at apps that can assist in staying unnoticed, perhaps getting carried away a but naybe but there was many many more on my activity some as simple as looking up Google and Samsung Internet browser on Google play !! Not been together long but something feels wrong, could what shes searching cause me harm

Answer (score 0):

All of these applications are normal for a Samsung phone, as indicated by `com.samsung accessibility`. None of these are hacking applications. It's improbable that access to your settings or accessibility settings alone could give enough access.

As mentioned in the comments on your post, mental health issues are not relavent here. Paranoia can be a sign of psychosis, this will be for your care provider and another stack exchange though. I do not know any, so feel free to comment down if you know!

If she had another account on your phone, taking a quick look into your settings would reveal another account.  If you are seriously concerned about your account being hijacked, change all your passwords. There should be good enough guides for each email and account provider (Google, Gmail, Outlook, Microsoft, etc)